# Login not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to make a Amazon scraper but it just isnt working for me.

My code

```
    login_url = 'https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?_encoding=UTF8&openid.assoc_handle=usflex&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Fyourstore%2Fhome%3Fie%3DUTF8%26action%3Dsign-out%26path%3D%252Fgp%252Fyourstore%252Fhome%26ref_%3Dnav_youraccount_signout%26signIn%3D1%26useRedirectOnSuccess%3D1'
data = urllib.urlencode({
        'action': 'login',
        'email': 'username..',
        'password': 's...',
        'appActionToken': 'hgrNSzj2BSD0Y27V7pd3pQeFo0A2cj3D',
        'Upgrade-Insecure -Requests': '1',
        'openid.pape.max_auth_age': "ape:MA==",
        "openid.return_to": "ape:aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYW1hem9uLmNvbS8/cmVmXz1uYXZfc2lnbmlu",
        "prevRID": "ape:UThNMkU4RUYxNzREMlpKUDRWRzI=",
        "openid.identity": "ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjAvaWRlbnRpZmllcl9zZWxlY3Q=",
        "openid.assoc_handle": "ape:dXNmbGV4",
        "openid.mode": "ape:Y2hlY2tpZF9zZXR1cA==",
        "openid.ns.pape": "ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvZXh0ZW5zaW9ucy9wYXBlLzEuMA==",
        "openid.claimed_id": "ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjAvaWRlbnRpZmllcl9zZWxlY3Q=",
        "pageId": "ape:dXNmbGV4",
        "openid.ns": "ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9w"})
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

cookie = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36')]

response = opener.open('https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?_encoding=UTF8&openid.assoc_handle=usflex&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com')
print(response.getcode())

response = opener.open('https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?_encoding=UTF8&openid.assoc_handle=usflex&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com', data=data)
print(response.getcode())

response = opener.open("https://www.amazon.com/") 
print response.read()
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Not getting any errors but when I print out the last source it doesn't indicate that I am logged it.